# Twilo Unanswered calls Should trigger a URL

Tags: twilio

Is it possible that if a call is triggered using API to a Number and the user doesn't attend the call a url should be triggered to tell my application that call was unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While create a call request to twilio we can pass parameters to it:

`status_callback` and `status_callback_method` I am using it in rails

```
 @client.account.calls.create(:from => 'xxxxxxx', :to => "xxxxx", :url =>"url", :method => :get, :status_callback=>"status_call_backurl", :status_callback_method=>:get)
```

Comment: I have just started using sales force to test the twilo integration.I have installed the twilo package and using the test account of twilo. But when i am sending the message it is giving exception Error Message TwilioRestException: Script-thrown exception
Stack Trace Class.TwilioRestClient: line 591, column 1. Your any help will be highly appreciated.